# Best way to make .io style game in java?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

So I have come up with an idea for a .io style game using java. (I know it isn't actually a .io, that's just the domain that is commonly used.) I would like to start out by making a grid and I have tried with JFrame and JPanel etc but I think im barking up the wrong tree...

Anyone got any useful advice in terms of making a game "space"/map? I'm a fair beginner but I'd be OK with a not-too-in-depth explanation, just want a a good point in the right direction. And yes, I know the IMMENSE amount of work that goes into the multiplayer networking and everything else like that but I just want to get the game up and running as a single player to start with.

I think other people would appreciate a decent answer to this question aswell...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use JavaFX? They have a [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) which might be what you want. If all you want is a grid-like background and not an actual grid like slither.io then I believe you can just draw an image to background. You can (should?) also use OpenGL. If you plan to use OpenGL then you can use [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/) or a game engine like [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You would have a much easier time doing this in JavaScript using an HTML5 canvas. You could even use the Socket.io framework for handling all the networking. There's tons of tutorials for that stuff on YouTube, and switching to JavaScript is stress-free. I learned the general syntax in under an hour after coming from Java/C++.